# Generic privileges: what do you think about it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't know if someone else already asked something like it but I'm new in this community and I think that it could be a good idea to create generic reputation for some privileges.
For example, for me it's not possible to comment on Stack Overflow and not in Super User.

Some privileges must remain limited to the section where the user has gained more reputation, for example the voting privileges, but some privileges should be "generic".

What do you think about this idea?

P.S.: I tried to search if this had already been suggested but I didn't find anything, sorry if this is a duplicate question.

EDIT: After the Sarnold's answer I would change a little my question:
If it is true that when a user, for example, has more than 200 rep on stackoverflow and he want to register on Superuser, it start already with 100 rep my question is: why don't  create more privilegies that abilitate these privilegies without adding rep?
Something like "Comments in any sites"...

Comment: FYI, what you just did with your edit makes this question a [chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), which is discouraged. At best, the result is a discussion, which isn't the goal here; at worst, older answers stop making sense entirely. In situations like this, please ask new questions instead; you can always include a link to the original question for context.

Comment: @ Popular demand : sorry but I don't know very well this site and its meccanism... however after @ laf comment I know that it works already like I suggest... in this case what is better? Flag this question as "Closed"? or delete it?

Comment: You can't vote to close this (not enough rep) or delete it (it has upvoted answers). Probably best to just let it age away and disappear on its own.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is one of the reasons behind the +100 given when someone with +200 reputation points joins another site in the stack; the +100 will quickly give access to some of the most important functions:

```
set bounties
comment everywhere
talk in chat
flag posts
vote up
create wiki posts
remove new user restrictions
participate in meta
create posts
```

(This list might vary from site to site; I stole it from the [Stack Overflow list of Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).)

Voting *down* requires 125, and that's alright -- it doesn't take too long to build up the extra 25 reputation on a new site.

I dearly miss the "edit" privilege when I participate on sites in the stack where I've got low reputation, but at least I can make edit *suggestions*, which is nice.

Comment: @ sarnold : I didn't know that... but if it is true, you are telling that it is "better" to register firstly to a single area and, when the user has 200 rep, register to others areas? I up your answer but edit my question...

Comment: @Filippo1980 Even if you register on 10 SE sites, as soon as you get 200 rep on one of these, you automatically get the 100 rep bonus on the other sites.

Comment: @ laf : ok thank you for your explanation...

Comment: I'm ambivalent.

Answer (score 4):

The privilege to post both questions and answers *is already* generic. Other things come with time.

Comment: @ Duncan Babbage : what do you mean? Are you talking about the same thing of Sarnold?

Comment: @Filippo1980 no, he means you don't need *any reputation at all* to ask or answer a question.

Comment: @ shog9 : ok, i'm newbie but I noted already this thing : I was reffering about "Other things come with time."...